# Collection serialization issues

Tags: java, serialization, collections, gson

So my issue is a bit complex. I've got one User class, which I put into ConcurrentHashMap<String, User>. One class corresponds to one user. Key is user's ID.

I'm using GSON to serialize this ConcurrentHashMap and save the data of my users.

Inside of user class i have multiple variables (ints, Strings, etc.) and few Collections.
Problem is in overwriting the file. 2 out of my 4 ArrayLists are serializing as usual, but when I add another ArrayList, or any collection for that matter, the collection won't show up in a file. However when I add a simple variable such as String or Int, the file updated and appends those values for every user. When new user is being created, those collections show up as nothing happened. I need to add those collections for already exsisting users.

My question is why in hell can't add another ArrayList to the class, and why it's not showing up in the file.

```
public class User {

private String nickname;
private String id;
private int coins;


  ...bunch of variables


private int bikes = 0;
private int scooters = 0;
private int goldIngots = 0;
private final ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>(); //showing up
private final ArrayList<Hotel> hotels = new ArrayList<>(); //showing up
private final ArrayList<AwardType> awards = new ArrayList<>(); //not showing up   



...Constructor


...Getters And Setters
```

[sample of UserClass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScGYC.png)

[collections inside UserClass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjoKe.png)

[how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSJin.png)

[values are not appending](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4TEO.png)

**EDIT**

AwardType is an enum. This list cointaining AwardType is not showing up for existing users, only for new ones.

**EDIT 1**

After adding Gson serializeNulls() option, the list is being added to the file but as a null.

```
"bikes": 0,
"scooters": 0,
"goldIngots": 0,
"cars": [],
"hotels": [],
"awards": null
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of your code; post the actual code.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I'm sorry, it is my first post on StackOverflow, I will post my code in the edit.

Comment: Do you have a no-arg constructor for your `User` class? When Gson does not find a no-arg constructor it creates an instance without invoking any constructor or initalizer blocks (therefore also not assigning default values). Please try adding a no-arg constructor (can be `private`) and see if that helps.

Comment: @Marcono1234 I have 3 args to the constructor. Those 3 args are nickname, id and coins. Rest of the variables is assigned by me to the default. For instance int bikes variable is by default equal to 0. I have methods such as setBikes() to manipulate those numbers.

Comment: I will try adding no-args constructor as you proposed.

Comment: @Marcono1234 THANK YOU!!!! It worked perfectly. If you be so kind, to tell me why can't I have normal 3-args constructor? I've been fighting this issue for over 2 days.

Comment: @John I added an answer which hopefully gives a bit more information. However, I just noticed that you are experiencing this issue during serialization (instead of **de**serialization). I assume the reason for this is that you are also deserializing the existing users from the JSON file. Therefore their field values will be `null` when you then serialize them again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you need to add a no-arg constructor (sometimes also called "default constructor") to your class. This constructor may be `private` (so you don't call it by accident).

This constructor is required for Gson to be able to create an instance and then afterwards update its field values during deserialization. Other constructors with parameters do not work because Gson cannot determine which JSON property matches which constructor parameter, and assuming default values (e.g. 0 and `null`) for the parameters might not be correct either in all situation.

If no no-arg constructor is detected Gson uses a specific JDK class called `sun.misc.Unsafe` to create an instance without calling any constructor and without executing any initializer block (including initializing fields). This can lead to issues such as the one you experienced. Additionally the `Unsafe` class might not be available in all environments. Due to this you should avoid relying on this behavior.

Alternatively you can also create an [`InstanceCreator`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/InstanceCreator.html) for your class, but in most cases it is easier to add a no-arg constructor.